# Hadoop Job and Task Tracker not working

Tags: hadoop, configuration, hdfs

when i start hadoop job tracker and task tracker not working.

I'm working with two computers. master- furkanb@master 192.168.2.135 and slave- detay@slave
192.168.2.250.

xml and hosts files the same on 2 computers.

I have written to the console jps.

## JPS

15568 Jps
12126 SecondaryNameNode
11812 NameNode
11934 DataNode
12314 ResourceManager

My host file

## /etc/hosts

> 127.0.0.1 localhost
>
> 127.0.1.1  ubuntu.ubuntu-domain    ubuntu
>
> 192.168.2.135     master
>
> 192.168.2.250  slave

## core-site.xml

```
<configuration>

<property>
   <name>fs.default.name</name>
   <value>hdfs://master:54310</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

## hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
   <name>dfs.replication</name>
   <value>2</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

## mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>

<property>
   <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
   <value>master:54311</value>
</property>

<property>
   <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
   <value>yarn</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

## yarn-site.xml

```
<configuration>
 <property>
 <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
 <value>mapreduce.shuffle</value>
 </property>
 <property>
 <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
 <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

Master Machine:

> /etc/hadoop/masters  furkanb@master
>
> /etc/hadoop/slaves furkanb@master detay@slave

Slave Machine:

> /etc/hadoop/slaves localhost

When i write start-all.sh on console :

```
This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh
14/04/09 14:52:58 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [master]
master: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.3.0/logs/hadoop-furkanb-namenode-master.out
furkanb@master: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.3.0/logs/hadoop-furkanb-datanode-master.out
detay@slave: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.3.0/logs/hadoop-detay-datanode-slave.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.3.0/logs/hadoop-furkanb-secondarynamenode-master.out
14/04/09 14:53:19 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.3.0/logs/yarn-furkanb-resourcemanager-master.out
furkanb@master: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.3.0/logs/yarn-furkanb-nodemanager-master.out
detay@slave: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.3.0/logs/yarn-detay-nodemanager-slave.out
```

I can reach localhost:50070 and master:50070. But i can't reach localhost:50030 or master:50030

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Yarn not classic mapreduce. You cannot find Jobtracker here. For checking the status of running applications you need to use resource manager's http port. ie 8088

Check out the following URL 
localhost:8088